# Skip one iteration in a for loop

Tags: java, iteration

How can I skip one iteration of a for loop like this one:

```
for (int i = 65; i <= 90; i++) {
  if (!(i == 73)) {
    uniq.add((char) i);
  }
}
```

`uniq` should contain the alphabet, excluding `'I'`.  Are there any other ways to solve this?  I'm just starting Java, and I'm trying to do this as simply as possible.

Comment: I would prefer `if (i != 73)` over `if (!(i == 73))`, but otherwise I think you have the most direct way already.  Another possibility is to add them all and then remove the one you don't want, but I'm not sure this is any clearer.

Comment: I tried to clean up and clarify your question, apologies if I mangled your meaning.  You can click "edit" to fix it if so.

Comment: Why not add all of them, and then explicitly remove `I` ?

Comment: @C.B. naively that would take O(n) time.  If you know which index `I` will end up in you can do better, but that's probably more brittle than the current solution.

Comment: Not if you are using the right data structure. Especially since `uniq` implies a `set` of some sort. However I would agree that with the right naming conventions and maybe a cast would make it more readable, unless there are more to remove.

Comment: @C.B. yes, you can do better with the right design.  However following your original comment verbatim would likely make matters worse.  If you want you can post your solution with the right data structure as an answer :)

Answer (score 4):

You could try something like this:

```
for (int i = 65; i <=90; i++) {
    if (i == 73) {
        continue;
    }                    // An else is not needed because the continue would skip
    uniq.add((char) i);  // over all of the code after it.
}
```

The keyword [continue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html) skips over the current iteration of the for loop, although for a single case such as this, I would expect your implementation to be just as, if not more, simple.
However, one thing I would change with your code is switching `!(i==73)` to `i != 73`, as the latter is more common and more readable.

Answer (score 2):

Under the covers, a [`char`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) is just a number between 0 and 65,535 (an unsigned `short`), and that means you can do arithmetic on `char`s, and even use them in loops.  This can make a lot of text-twiddling code much easier to read.  Consider:

```
for (char c = 'A'; c <= 'Z'; c++) {
  if (c != 'I') {
    uniq.add(c);
  }
}
```

Now it's immediately clear we're looping over the ASCII alphabet, adding each `char` to a list, and skipping `'I'`.

---

As @C.B. and I discussed in the comments, you could also do:

```
for (char c = 'A'; c <= 'Z'; c++) {
  uniq.add(c);
}
uniq.remove('I');
```

However depending on your data stricture, this could be problematic.  If `uniq` is a `List`, the `.remove()` operation has to loop over the whole list, which is needlessly wasteful.

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of @Rezwan's answer; and he shot first.

Comment: @tucuxi It's similar to @Rezwan's answer, but note that `c` is a `char` directly, avoiding the need for casting.  My answer also provides more context than just "use my code".  If "shot first" is more important than "more context" for you, so be it.  I'm just trying to help.

Comment: I failed to notice the difference at first glance. No offence was meant. However, citing similar answers before submitting many hours later would have been good form.

Answer (score 1):

Direct implementation of the following code should work.
With this method you would not be require to know corresponding ACSII or Unicode representations of letters.

```
for (int i = 'A'; i <= 'Z'; i++) {
  if (i != 'I') {
    uniq.add((char) i);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're probably already doing it one of the simplest ways possible.

A more verbose, but perhaps less elegant (although arguably easier to read) way to accomplish the same thing could be something like the following:

```
for (int i = 65; i < 73; i++) {
            uniq.add((char) i);
}

for (int i = 74; i <= 90; i++) {
            uniq.add((char) i);
}
```

When you're writing source code I like to think that you're writing for a human, not the computer. Try to emphasize readability over shortness.